# batch review files, ascertain the correct file extension and set the correct file extension type for each file

Tags: batch, file-extension

Ive got a folder with video files which are a few different file extensions. eg : .m4v, .avi, .mp4, .mkv

I deleted all the extensions off the file names using a batch renaming tool, but when ive done this all the files now show up a unix executable files. (im on a mac so i think this is just the default).

I have a couple of hundred files like this, is there any way i can batch review the files, ascertain the correct file extension and set the correct file extension type for each file.

Comment: AVI may be detecred by `RIFF`  (offset 0) + `AVI`  (offset 8) signatures. MP4 may be detected by `ftypmmp4` (offset 4) signature. M4V may be detected by `mtypM4V` (offset 4) signature.  But batch processing cannot do this.

Comment: On macOS the [file](https://ss64.com/osx/file.html) command will identify .m4v, .avi and .mp4.

Comment: ffmpeg will output data about a file you pass with the -i option, I renamed an `.mkv` file to just `test` and did this `ffmpeg -i test 2>&1 | grep encoder` and got `encoder         : libebml v1.3.6 + libmatroska v1.4.9`

Answer (score 1):

In macOS 10.14 Mojave the [file](https://ss64.com/osx/file.html) command correctly identifies .m4v, .avi and .mp4 from the file contents.  Note the version of `file` on macOS is outdated compared to the [current version](https://github.com/file/file) and so some other filetypes may not be identified correctly.  For example a test **mkv** downloaded from [www.sample-videos.com](https://sample-videos.com/index.php) was **not** identified.

For filetypes that `file` *can* correctly identify you can append the relevant suffix by identifying the file and then renaming it.

```
file * | grep <FILETYPE> | sed s'<SOMETHING>' | xargs -I % mv % %<.EXTENSION>
```

---

**Filetypes identified**

I downloaded some sample files from [here](https://file-examples.com/index.php/sample-video-files/sample-mp4-files/) and [there](https://sample-videos.com/index.php), ranamed them  *file_example_something* and removed the extensions.  From that directory you can see everything except `MKV` is identified and has filetype in the descrition provided by *file* command:

```
A1398% file file_example_*
file_example_AVI_480_750kB:         RIFF (little-endian) data, AVI, 480 x 270, 30.00 fps, video: H.264 X.264 or H.264, audio: (stereo, 48000 Hz)
file_example_AVI_480_750kB copy:    RIFF (little-endian) data, AVI, 480 x 270, 30.00 fps, video: H.264 X.264 or H.264, audio: (stereo, 48000 Hz)
file_example_M4V_720:               ISO Media, Apple iTunes Video (.M4V) Video
file_example_M4V_720 copy:          ISO Media, Apple iTunes Video (.M4V) Video
file_example_MKV_1280x720_1mb:      , created: Thu Jul 11 00:22:26 1974, modified: Sun Mar 26 05:53:06 2028
file_example_MKV_1280x720_1mb copy: , created: Thu Jul 11 00:22:26 1974, modified: Sun Mar 26 05:53:06 2028
file_example_MP4_480_1_5MG:         ISO Media, MP4 v2 [ISO 14496-14]
file_example_MP4_480_1_5MG copy:    ISO Media, MP4 v2 [ISO 14496-14]
```

You can therefore extract the file names of a certain type if you make a couple of assumptions (for example you don't have `:` in a file name and you don't have `.M4V` files with **.avi** in the file name)

**Example for .m4v**

For example, this uses [grep](https://ss64.com/osx/grep.html) (to select a file type from *find* results description) and then [sed](https://ss64.com/osx/sed.html) to [remove](https://serverfault.com/a/398193) everything after the first `:`.

```
A1398% file * | grep .M4V | sed s'/:.*[^:]*$//'
file_example_M4V_720
file_example_M4V_720 copy
```

If the results look reasonable you can then [rename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22388480/how-to-pipe-the-results-of-find-to-mv-in-linux) them - in this case only `M4V`

**M4V Correction**

```
file * | grep .M4V | sed s'/:.*[^:]*$//' | xargs -I % mv % %.m4v
```

**Results**

```
A1398% ls -la file_example_M4V*
-rw-r--r--@ 1 hali  staff  3538130 Dec 26 18:31 file_example_M4V_720
-rw-r--r--@ 1 hali  staff  3538130 Dec 26 18:31 file_example_M4V_720 copy
A1398%
A1398% file * | grep .M4V | sed s'/:.*[^:]*$//' | xargs -I % mv % %.m4v
A1398% ls -la file_example_M4V*
-rw-r--r--@ 1 hali  staff  3538130 Dec 26 18:31 file_example_M4V_720 copy.m4v
-rw-r--r--@ 1 hali  staff  3538130 Dec 26 18:31 file_example_M4V_720.m4v
```

---

Therefore for identifiable filetypes in your question:

```
file * | grep .M4V | sed s'/:.*[^:]*$//' | xargs -I % mv % %.m4v
```

```
file * | grep .MP4 | sed s'/:.*[^:]*$//' | xargs -I % mv % %.mp4
```

```
file * | grep .AVI | sed s'/:.*[^:]*$//' | xargs -I % mv % %.avi
```

Comment: Thanks so much, i updated the question last night to also include .mkv files would the above work for them also ?

Comment: I tested a mkv downloaded from the internet and `file` did **not** identify it (you can see results in the answer - it just shows garbage creation data).  On macOS the definitions are in `/usr/share/file/magic` with video definitions seemingly in the files `animation` and `riff`.  There is nothing there for mkv and neither is there in latest source on [github](https://github.com/file/file/blob/master/magic/Magdir/animation). mkv is not a video format anyway - it is a container that can contain anything (eg avi files).  If you get rid of the other types you can just try renaming the rest mkv...